# What is the difference between base url and base link url?

Tags: php, magento, url

Every time when we setup new magento site or configure site to live domain we put base url and base link url same, but I haven't gone in deep why we put same? If both should contain same url then why magento have this field?

I just want to know is there any special purpose for this field. Hope someone will clarify me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Magento for the most part uses `base_url` for its URL generation. If you do a grep on the app folder, you'll find that `base_url` returns 200 hits in 46 files, while `base_link_url` returns 29 hits in 9 files

The `base_link_url` is used in the following:

- XmlConnect module(s)
- Paypalflowlink module(s)

Yep, that's about it. For everything else there's `base_url`

Comment: thanks nick, i will look into these modules to know more why these modules are using base_link_url .